# Capture rendered HTML page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bitmap, capture

Is it possible to capture the rendered HTML page from Javascript.

- I want to be able to create a "minimap" of an HTML page for quick navigation.

Comment: You're going to be more specific than that. There's probably a way to do what you want, but you're going to have to tell us what you want before we can suggest it...

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Grooveek actually managed to answer my question. But I basically want a HTML2image function from js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com)
It does some good things, even if it's not perfect

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

That is the whole "rendered" (ie. live/DOM-complete) HTML, but I'm not sure this is what you want.

You would be better defining what it is you want to create a map of, for example headings etc, then you can use `getElementsByTagName('h1')` (for example) to grab all of the H1's on the page.

If you're talking an actual image as rendered by a browser, you can take a look at [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) and it's `wkhtmltoimage` counterpart, which will take HTML (or a web address) as an input and convert it either to a text-complete PDF, or a static image. Have used this neat app before on large projects so it's definitely reliable, also uses WebKit so CSS3/JS compatible.

Comment: I want the rendering, i.e. the pixels. Thanks for your answer. :-)

Comment: @BentRasmussen Ah in that case, wkhtmltoimage is definitely what you should try, if you want it server side of course :)

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltoimage is only of use for static html pages.
If you have user selections or a canvas with some drawing (other than the default when first rendered) wkhtmltoimage will not help.